# Wordpress: Only show future posts minus one day

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a loop that runs perfect for events and only shows future posts. The issue is that I would love to keep posts that are no longer future posts in the loop for an extra day.

Example:
So if the event (or post that is scheduled) is for 8pm on the 3rd. As of now it is removed at 8pm (which is an issue because it might last for 4 hours).

I would like posts to remain up for an extra day, or time that I would be able to alter.

Here is my current code:

```
<?php
                    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 50, 'post_status' => 'future', 'order' => 'ASC' );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
                        <div class="teaser-event <?php the_field('highlight') ?>">
                            <div class="event-meta gold">
                            <div class="event-date"><?php the_time('M d'); ?></div>
                                <div class="event-time"><?php the_time('g:i A'); ?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="event-title">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php  endwhile; else: ?>
                        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the time parameters for `WP_Query` are able to specify definite time spans but not indefinite ones, e.g. posts from now into the future. The WordPress docs recommends using the [posts_where filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) for time-relative queries. So you might put this in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where($where = '') {
    // posts from yesterday into the future
    $where .= ' AND post_date >= "' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day')) . '"';
    return $where;
}
```

And in your code above you could do:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 50, 'order' => 'ASC');
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

The adding and removing filter doesn't make this the most elegant solution, so you could probably clean it up by defining a custom `function get_recent_and_future_posts()` in your theme's `functions.php` that returns whatever object `$loop` is.

Comment: Wow! This looks awesome, and I appreciate the quick help! Some of this coding is a bit beyond my skill set, so I am curious if you explain what the ... and second part of the second code section is for. Also, am curious if I need to edit any of this before using it?

Comment: I removed the `...` and the second code section is what you want to replace the beginning of your code with. I'm not entirely sure if it'll work. Stick it in there and try it out.

Comment: Ok looks close! It's only showing posts within the last day..I need those and future posts :)

Comment: Do those future posts you want have post_type = event? Make sure the post_per_page = 50 isn't limiting it either.

Comment: They do, and it isn't. My code works for what it's written for. The new code you gave seems to limit it to only posts from the last day

Comment: any fix for that? :) @David Xia

Comment: A quick and dirty fix would be to repeat the code you had originally that displayed the future posts. This way you'll get both. I'm not sure why it's not working as is.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Down the page there's a section called "Time Parameters".

I think instead of looking for post_status in the future you want to look for posts with a date greater than current date - 1 day.